# Update table if exist or insert if not

Tags: sql

I have 2 SQL tables with same column label, Table1 and Table2.

I want to update Table1 with value of Table2 if there is a same value for an attribute.

The tables has `CODE`, `POSITION`, `DESCRIPTION` as columns.

I do this:

```
UPDATE Table1
SET CODE = Table2.CODE,
    POSITION= Table2.POSITION
FROM Table2
WHERE DESCRIPTION = Table2.DESCRIPTION
```

It works, but if in the `DESCRIPTION` Value of `Table2` is not present into `Table1`, I want to insert the entire row, in other words I need to do something like:

```
UPDATE IF DESCRIPTION EXISTS
ELSE INSERT
```

How can I do this?

Comment: Please do not spam your question with irrelevant tags! Please add the one product tag that you actually use!

Comment: https://www.sqlshack.com/understanding-the-sql-merge-statement/

Comment: Which database provider are you using?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this from first-principals in 2 steps

1. Update the existing values like you have done:

   ```
   UPDATE Table1
   SET 
         CODE= t2.CODE,
         POSITION= t2.POSITION
   FROM Table1 t1
   INNER JOIN Table2 t2 ON t1.DESCRITPION = t2.DESCRITPION
   ```
2. Then you can insert the missing records

   ```
   INSERT INTO Table1 (CODE, POSITION, DESCRITPION)
   SELECT CODE, POSITION, DESCRITPION
   FROM Table2 t2
   WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT DESCRITPION 
                     FROM Table1 t1 
                     WHERE t1.DESCRITPION = t2.DESCRITPION)
   ```

Most RDBMS have a `MERGE` statement that allows you to combine these two queries into a single atomic operation, you'll need to check the documentation for your vendor, but an [MS SQL Server MERGE](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/merge-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16) solution looks like this:

```
MERGE INTO Table1 AS tgt
      USING Table2 AS src
      ON tgt.DESCRITPION = src.DESCRITPION
      WHEN MATCHED 
          THEN UPDATE SET CODE= src.CODE,
                          POSITION= src.POSITION
      WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN
          INSERT (CODE, POSITION, DESCRITPION)
          VALUES (src.CODE, src.POSITION, src.DESCRITPION)
```

An additional benefit to the `MERGE` clause is that it simplifies capturing the *changed state* into the `OUTPUT` clause which allows for some complex logic all while keeping the query as a single operation without having to manually create and track transaction scopes.